# Reading CSV file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I don't know why its not working. I am new to this field. I have saved a file data.csv as well but its nothing showing up.

```
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Graph</title>

 <script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com
 /ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


var options = {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    defaultSeriesType: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: []
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Units'
    }
},
series: []
};

$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
// Split the lines
var lines = data.split('\n');

// Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    var items = line.split(',');

    // header line containes categories
    if (lineNo === 0) {
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
        });
    }

    // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
    else {
        var series = {
            data: []
        };
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo === 0) {
                series.name = item;
            } else {
                series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
            }
        });

        options.series.push(series);

    }

});

// Create the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

2.my data.csv file looks like following:

```
            Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas,Plums
            John,8,4,6,5
            Jane,3,4,2,3
            Joe,86,76,79,77
            Janet,3,16,13,15
```

I want to generate interactive graphs which take there data from an Excel file which is on the other password protected website (I know the password) but those files get updated with time.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Maybe you can use console.log and log some variables at some point in your code to see if they are what you expect them to be. You can see the console with the errors and logs when you press F12

Comment: Are you including the HighCharts javascript library in your HTML?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 I did but still not working, i cant see anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A get request is asynchronous, you are treating it as synchronous.

The line `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);` is running before the Ajax call is returned.

You need to initialize the chart after the data has been loaded. [AKA in the callback]

Also in your code above, I do not see the JavaScript file for the highcharts. That would also be a big issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment can you tell me how can I do that, I am a beginner and i just started with all this..

Comment: var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); should be in the next line after:  options.series.push(series);

Comment: I tried still does not work